# Paypal Braintree Paypal security key is not supported

Tags: paypal, key, braintree

I'm testing paypal braintree in sandbox environment on a mobile app.

When I try to make a payment with Braintree, then after trying to log in to Paypal I get the following error:

"Login failed. Paypal security key is not supported."

Does anyone know why or what's wrong? Any information about why or when this error appears will be appreciated.

By the way: should I have to log in to Paypal in sandbox environment (or should it be only in production environment)?

Answer (score 0):

in sandbox you can login with sandbox accounts, you can create them from dev page
the same message shown when i use old sdk and i had 2fa enabled on my account